# What is the best way to find and replace urls on a giant text?

Tags: regex

I have I huge backup of posts of my blog. All posts has images like:

"http://www.mysite.com/nonono-nonono.jpg"

or

"http://www.mysite.com/nonono-nonono.gif"

or even

"http://www.mysite.com/nonono.jpg"

But I have other links for urls on the same domain like ""http://www.mysite.com/category/post.html" and I just want to replace urls for the images (luckly all images are on the root of the website).

I need to learn RegExp to do that? Is there any powerful tool to find and replace texts like this? Thanks

Comment: What is the replacement string for an image url? (edit your question to add this info). For example, what is the desirable result for "http://www.mysite.com/nonono.jpg"?

Comment: Please use example.com instead of mysite.com as described ini RFC 2606.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions will be your best bet... maybe something like this (based on the one from [strfriend](http://strfriend.com/))?

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.(jpg|gif|png))?
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are certainly one way to do it, and probably the most flexible.  But if all of your image urls start with "http://www.mysite.com/" and end with ".jpg", then you can use string manipulation functions.  For example, if you have a string variable called s, that you want to test:

```
const string mysite = "http://www.mysite.com/";
const string jpg = ".jpg";
string newString = string.Empty;
if (s.BeginsWith(mysite))
{
    if (s.EndsWith(jpg))
    {
        string textToReplace = s.SubString(mysite.Length, s.Length - mysite.Length - jpg.Length);
        newString = s.Replace(textToReplace, "whatever you want to replace it with.");
    }
}
```

It's a rather brute force method, but it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using RegExp on EditPad Pro. I'll find a good tutorial for beginners also. Thanks for the tip @CalvinR

Comment: You can find a good regex tutorial right in EditPad Pro's help file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with regular expressions, but I'd probably write a Python script using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html):

```
# fix_imgs.py
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
  contents = open(filename).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)

  # replacing each img tag
  for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    img.src = img.src.replace("http://www.mysite.com", "http://www.example.com")

  new_contents = str(soup)
  output_filename = "replaced." + filename
  open(output_filename, "w").write(new_contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace all filenames by '`new_image_name_here`' in image urls:

```
$ perl -pe's~(http://.*?/)[^/]+?\.(jpg|gif)\b~$1new_image_name_here.$2~g' huge_file.html > output.html
```

To replace a `netloc` part by 'www.othersite.org' in '`http://<netloc>/<image_path>`':

```
$ perl -pe's~(?<=http://)[^/]+(?=/(?:[^/]+/)*[^/]+?\.(?:jpg|gif)\b)~www.othersite.org~g' huge_file.html > output.html
```

These regexs are simple therefore they are easily fooled. Use more specific regexs for your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think you should learn regular expressions regardless, it's a great tool to have up your sleeve especially in situations such as this. They are an extremely powerful tool for string manipulation, Perl is also a great language to learn at the same time as it makes using Reg Exps a breeze.